# C++ How to create a map from two other maps

Tags: c++

How to create map  `MyMap3` as:

```
std::map< vector<std::pair<int, int>>, int > MyMap3
```

**Example:**

```
 MyMap3[0] = ((1,3) , (1,5), 7 ) // 5 = 4 + 3
 MyMap3[1] = ( (2,1) , (2,4), 6 ) // 6 = 1 + 5
```

Where the key = (vector of pairs) extract from 'MyMap1',

and the value = the sum of the pairs' values  in 'MyMap2'.

I also don't care about the pair order, (2,4) is the same as (4,2)

```
std::map <int, vector<pair<int, int>> > MyMap1;
std::map< std::pair< int, int>, int>  MyMap2;
```

Here is an **Example:**

> ```
> MyMap1[0] = (0, (1,3) , (1,5) )
> MyMap1[1] = (1, (2,1) , (2,4) )
>
> MyMap2[0] = ( (1,3) , 4 )
> MyMap2[1] = ( (1,5) , 3 )
> MyMap2[2] = ( (2,1) , 1 )
> MyMap2[3] = ( (4,2) , 5 )
> ```

I don't know how to do that, and this is my try:

```
    std::map <int, vector<pair<int, int>> > ::iterator it1 = MyMap1.begin();
    std::map<std::pair< int, int>, int> ::iterator it2 = MyMap2.begin();
//  std::map< vector<pair<int, int> >, int> MyMap3;
    std::map< pair<int, int> , int> MyMap3;

    int i = 0;

    while (it1 != MyMap1.end())
    {
        vector< pair<int, int> > temp = MyMap1[i];
        vector< pair<int, int> > ::iterator it3 = temp.begin();

        while (it3 != temp.end())
        {
            int a = it2->first.first;
            int b = it2->first.second;


            while (it2 != MyMap2.end())
            {
                if (it3 == MyMap2.find(std::make_pair(a, b))
                    MyMap3[std::make_pair(a, b)] += it2->second;

                else
                    ++it2;
            }
            ++it3;
            ++i;
        }
        ++it1;
    }
```

I have syntax error in:

```
if (it3 == MyMap2.find(make_pair(a, b)))
    MyMap3[std::make_pair(a, b)] += it2->second;
```

Comment: `MyMap1[0] = (0, (1,3) , (1,5) )` - this is supposed to be a map from an `int` to a `vector` of `pair<int, int>`s. So what does that first `0` mean in the list? That's not a pair of `int`s.

Comment: Well your `it3` have type `vector< pair<int, int> > ::iterator` while object you are calling find from is `std::map<std::pair< int, int>, int>`. Something is definitely not right.

Comment: @joseph-mansfield
I have map `AssociatedItem` like this:  <br/>
`(1, (2,3,4))  <br/>
(2, (1,3,4,5))  <br/>
(3, (1,2,4))  <br/>
(4, (1,2,3,5))  <br/>
(5, (2,4))  <br/>
`

And I generate all subsets of size k (input by user), for each entry in the map, and I save the result in `MyMap1`, see this code  [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c414654d9720af)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confuse, i decipher you want for each key in map1 to sum the value of each pair in the vector found in the map2 to a single value, and store the result with the map1 key. Not really what your code do…

Example result : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4d77c77fa6896c1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <map>
#include <utility>

using Map1 = std::map< int, std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>>;
using Map2 = std::map< std::pair<int,int>, int >;
using Map3 = std::map< int, int >;

Map3 foo( Map1 const & m1, Map2 const & m2 ) {
    auto m2end = m2.end(); // a constant call is move outside the loop
    Map3 result;
    for( auto & v1 : m1 ) { // each entry in m1 is made of the key as first and the value as second
        for( auto & p1 : v1.second ) { // iterate over the vector of pair
            auto v2it = m2.find( p1 ); // search for the pair
            if ( v2it != m2end ) {
                result[v1.first] += v2it->second; // if the pair was found, add the value for it to the result, using the map1 key as key
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T,typename S>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T,S>& pair )
{
    os << "{ " << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << " }";
    return os;
}
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    os << "( ";
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ", ";
    }
    os << " )";
    return os;
}

template<typename T,typename S>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::map<T,S>& map)
{
    for (auto& el : map)
    {
        os << el.first << " : " << el.second << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Map1 m1 { { 0, { {1,3}, {1,5}} }, { 1, { {2,1}, {2,4}} }, };
    Map2 m2 { { {1,3}, 4 }, { {1,5}, 3 }, { {2,1}, 1 }, { {2,4}, 5 }, };

    auto m3 = foo( m1, m2);

    std::cout << "m1 :\n" << m1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m2 :\n" << m2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m3 :\n" << m3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already defined : `std::map <int, vector<pair<int, int>> > MyMap1;` and `std::map<std::pair< int, int>, int>  MyMap2;`  as global,  if I redefine them to `using MyMap1= std::map< int, std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>>;` and  `using MyMap2= std::map< std::pair<int,int>, int >;`  I will get syntax error, in every code has MyMap1, and MyMap2.

Comment: I also, used `Map3 foo(std::map <int, vector<pair<int, int>> > const &m1 = MayMap1, std::map<std::pair< int, int>, int> const &m2 = MayMap2)` but in your code, `result[v1.first] += v2it->second; // if the pair was found, add the value for it to the result, using the map1 key as key` I need add the value, and add the pair, **example:** ` result[0] = ((1,3) , (1,5), 7 ) // 5 = 4 + 3 ` and `
 result[1] = ( (2,1) , (2,4), 6 ) // 6=1+5 `

Comment: result[0] = ((1,3) , (1,5), 7 ) // 5 = 4 + 3 `  has absolytely no means, what do you want in the map exactly, in a map, we have that relation, `map[key] = value` you really should edit the post to reflect what you except to be in the map

Comment: I want to the result map,  Map3 as: std::map< vector<std::pair<int, int>>, int > Map3, where the key are vector<std::pair<int, int>> and the value is the sum the these pairs

Comment: How do you define the ordering between two vector of pair to use that as a key ?

Comment: I really don't know, I don't know how to do that, I was trying for the last week and couldn't figure it out

Comment: I EVEN try when I full MyMap1, I insert its value that in MyMap2, I'm going to put my code for full MyMap1, in the following comment.

Comment: Edit your question to fix it instead, for example, you do not use the key from Map1, you seems to not understand what is a map…

Comment: this was my code for MyMap1: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c414654d9720af